# Why is MAX PAYNE 3 so Huge?

Tags: max-payne-3

What can be the reason behind a 35GB game ?
As I believe Windows 7 has much more programming that Max Payne 3 game but still Windows 7 is much smaller ! So what does it contain  that makes it such big ?

Comment: Hi, Sourav.  I have voted to close your question because we can't answer it; it's entirely speculative.

Comment: See [this Meta topic](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2429/6066) for more detail.  Also check out the [FAQ] and if you have any other questions that would be a better fit here, please feel free to ask them!

Comment: Lack of engine optimization and game assets optimization, I reckon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The majority of the installation size for modern games is resources: music, models, textures, pre-rendered cutscenes, etc. While the actual code takes up some space, it is fairly negligible compared to the resources.

Additionally, a quote from Rockstar indicates that "The installed size of Max Payne 3 is attributed to the no-compromise quality of its assets which have already pushed console disc space to the limits. A good portion of the extra space on PC can be attributed to increased texture size which is four times that of the consoles. In addition, the audio quality is significantly higher than the consoles due to lower compression rates which increase fidelity. Again, this comes back to the range of possibilities that the PC platform opens up for us."

Since not all PCs can handle these massive textures, they have also included lower-resolution versions of all these textures, further inflating the installation size.

Source: [geforce.com article](http://www.geforce.com/optimize/guides/max-payne-3-benchmarked-in-a-new-york-minute/#1)